Viewing multiple plots with offset dataframes
I am trying to view multiple current vs time plots stacked on top of each other, with the same x axis but viewing current plots. I got my code to this point with ChatGPT (I'm not the best at coding in general, and want to make sure I understand instead of just relying on AI). I was given this directory method for reading the dataframes using subplots, and then the defined offset. I was originally given an offset value to plug into the y axis plot, but it made the data more scrunched as the current got smaller, so I changed it to constant offest, and it makes my plots evenly spaced, but now the peaks are too small to view.
This is my current code:
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

directory = r"LocationofCSVFiles"
separator = "," # Character that separates each value inside file
fExtension = ".csv" # Extension of the file storing the data

def ReadCSV(file_path):
    'Function to read CSV file into a DataFrame.'
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=separator, engine="python")
        return df
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading file {file_path}: {e}")
        return pd.DataFrame()

def PlotAllData(allData):
    'Plot all data from multiple DataFrames in a single figure with different y-axes and offsets.'
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    
    # offset = 0  # Start with no offset
    
    constant_offset = 1

    for i, df in enumerate(allData, start=1):
        if df.empty:
            continue
        
        # Convert the time column to numeric values
        time_col = df.columns[0]
        df[time_col] = pd.to_numeric(df[time_col], errors='coerce')
        
        # Set the time column as index
        df = df.set_index(time_col)
        
        # Plot each column with an offset
        for j, column in enumerate(df.columns):
            ax1.plot(df.index, df[column] + i*constant_offset, label=f"{column}", linewidth = 1, alpha=0.95)
        
        # offset += df.iloc[:, 0].max() * 1  # Increase offset based on max value of the current dataset

    ax1.set_xlabel('Time (s)',size='18')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Transient Current', size='18')
    ax1.legend(loc='best', bbox_to_anchor=(1.15, 0.5))
    
    plt.xlim(0,0.5)
    
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.show()

# Read all CSV files from the directory
allData = []
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(fExtension):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        df = ReadCSV(file_path)
        if not df.empty:
            allData.append(df)

PlotAllData(allData)

I got what I expected in the form of nice offset plots, but the scale of the y axis on the individual plots are too small to make out the peaks I want to compare across data points.
My main question is how to change the scale of the subplots without changing the scale of the overall figure or offest between them. I think the scale gets zoomed out when the plots are evenly spaced, but I want to view a very small y-range within each of those offset subplots. Should I use something in plt.yscale?
I'm also willing to try a completely different set of commands, but I'm assuming the for loop is necessary to use the same x axis across different iterations and that the offset (whether or not it's constant) is necessary to get the stacked plot visual I'm looking for.
Thanks a ton for any suggestions! (as well as tips to feel more solid in my coding, rather than feeling like I'm just nodding along with what AI/Stack overflow gives me)
